# ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings returns null when called in autostart

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-7

I have the following line of code:

```
MsgBox(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Path"))
```

and inside the app.config file this xml:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="PATH" value="myPath"/>
</appSettings>
```

I then deploy the solution and save it (the exe and the xml-config file) to the appdata-roaming path:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\<solutionname>
```

when I run it by double click, the massage-box shows the value "myPath". When I set it to run in autostart and restart my machine, the massege-box is empty (null). Why the config-xml file can't be read on autostart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider having a look at this documentation [ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

It says :

> Client applications use a global configuration that applies to all
>   users, separate configurations that apply to individual users, and
>   configurations that apply to **roaming users**. The userLevel value
>   determines the location of the configuration file being opened. It
>   indicates whether it has no user level (the configuration file is in
>   the same directory as the application) or has a per-user level (the
>   configuration file is in an application settings path determined by
>   the user level type.).

I'm not sure if this is relevant (since you said it works when you double click) . But no harm if you try.